# Can't delete image of server using Froala editor

Tags: javascript, php

I have followed carefully the installation guide on https://editor.froala.com/docs. Everything works beautifully, except for deleting image of my server.

I uploaded an image in the editor -> Image was saved in uploads folder on my local server. But when i chose to delete the that image in the editor -> it is deleted from the editor but it is still in the upload folder, although i tried the guide on this website. I tried with firebug but it did not tell any error.

Here is JS code which sends request to remove_image.php file:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#froala')
.editable({
// Set the image upload URL.
inlineMode: false,
imageMove: true,
height: 300,
imageUploadURL: 'upload.php',
imageUploadParam: "file",
imageDeleteURL: "remove_image.php"
})
.on('editable.afterRemoveImage', function (e, editor, $img) {
// Set the image source to the image delete params.
editor.options.imageDeleteParams = {src: $img.attr('src')};

// Make the delete request.
editor.deleteImage($img);
});

});
</script>
```

Here is the remove_image.php which handle deleted request from JS (copied from their guide). This will actually delete the image from upload folder. But it does not. The image is still there.

```
<?php
// Get src.
$src = $_POST["src"];

// Check if file exists.
if (file_exists(getcwd() . $src)) {
  // Delete file.
  unlink(getcwd() . $src);
}
?>
```

Ah, I found Post details in firebug as follow:

```
Parameters
src uploads/6bb7897cfcf2116c4dd04b97031652376bdaf144.png
Source
src=uploads%2F6bb7897cfcf2116c4dd04b97031652376bdaf144.png
```

There is extra %2F in front of image file name. This seems to be error but i dont know how to fix this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the first line from PHP with `$src = urldecode($_POST["src"]);` should do the trick.

Basically you have to replace `%2F` with `/`.

Comment: Replacing %2F with / where in the remove_image.php? Please advise furthur, i tried $src = urldecode($_POST["src"]); but did not work

Comment: Yes in remove_image.php.